# How to search in array of object in mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

Suppose the mongodb document(table) 'users' is

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: {
        first: 'John',
        last: 'Backus'
    },
    birth: new Date('Dec 03, 1924'),
    death: new Date('Mar 17, 2007'),
    contribs: ['Fortran', 'ALGOL', 'Backus-Naur Form', 'FP'],
    awards: [
        {
            award: 'National Medal',
            year: 1975,
            by: 'NSF'
        },
        {
            award: 'Turing Award',
            year: 1977,
            by: 'ACM'
        }
    ]
}
// ...and other object(person)s
```

I want to find the person who has the award 'National Medal' and must be awarded in year 1975
There could be other persons who have this award in different years.

How can I find this person using award type and year. So I can get exact person.

Answer (score 586, accepted):

The right way is:

```
db.users.find({awards: {$elemMatch: {award:'National Medal', year:1975}}})
```

`$elemMatch` allows you to match more than one component within the same array element.

Without `$elemMatch` mongo will look for users with National Medal in some year and some award in the year 1975, but not for users with National Medal in 1975.

See [MongoDB $elemMatch Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) for more info. See [Read Operations Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#arrays) for more information about querying documents with arrays.

Comment: i.e. elemMatch matches award 'and' year (as opposed to award 'or' year)

Comment: how do we query only those documents that has first name as John and award as national medal in simple way? we do it with aggregate and iterating through awards array but wanted to know simple query

Comment: if year would be an array of strings, how would the query look like?

Comment: @Gobliins the same, except year would be a string

Answer (score 33):

Use `$elemMatch` to find the array of a particular object

```
db.users.findOne({"_id": id},{awards: {$elemMatch: {award:'Turing Award', year:1977}}})
```

Comment: passing two objects to findOne, is this essentially a "subquery"? IE, we find the _ID = ID then search inside of that using $elemMatch?

Answer (score 17):

as explained in above answers Also, to return only one field from the entire array you can use [`projection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) into find. and use `$`

```
db.getCollection("sizer").find(
  { awards: { $elemMatch: { award: "National Medal", year: 1975 } } },
  { "awards.$": 1, name: 1 }
);
```

will be return

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: {
        first: 'John',
        last: 'Backus'
    },
    awards: [
        {
            award: 'National Medal',
            year: 1975,
            by: 'NSF'
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do this in two ways:

1. ElementMatch - `$elemMatch` (as explained in above answers)

   `db.users.find({ awards: { $elemMatch: {award:'Turing Award', year:1977} } })`
2. Use `$and` with `find`

   `db.getCollection('users').find({"$and":[{"awards.award":"Turing Award"},{"awards.year":1977}]})`