# How to query Mongodb for embedded array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb structure like.

> The structure of the place model

```
{.....
  amenities: [
    {
      name: "wifi",
      is_free: true
    },
    {
      name: "projector",
      is_free: false,
      price: "50"
    },
    ...........
    ...........
    ...........
  ]
.....}
```

I want to do a query where, I want to search for a place which is having some set of amenities exist in the place irrespective of the `price & is_free` fields. How can I do it inside the mongodb / mongoose query.

> I want list of places which are having set of amenities like wifi and
>   projector as a output.

Comment: Your question is not clear. So what you have tried and expected result.

Comment: you want to find out those amenities who has price & is_free both

Comment: Price and is_free doesn't matter. I want the place which are having amenities like 'wifi' and 'projector'.

Comment: I have modified the question. Please have a look. @Shrabanee

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search in array of object in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040562/how-to-search-in-array-of-object-in-mongodb)

Comment: I just want to know will it work for more than one `$elemMatch`. @aarosil

Comment: I am assuming that you have a collection 'places' in whose documents, you have an embedded array 'amneties'. And you want to find only those places in which 'amneties' exist. Is it what you need?

Comment: Yes you are correct @Manish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db.places.find({$and: [{'amenities.name': 'wifi'}, {'amenities.name':'projector'}])
```

It will find the places which have all amneties specified in an array `['wifi', 'projector']`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: not only having amenities. But it should have specific amenities. Your answer will not solve my problem

Comment: Find those places which have all ameneties specified in an array like:  ['wifi', 'loudspeakers', 'phone']. Is it what you need?

Comment: Yes! That is what I want. But your query doesn't do that. It will search only amenities filed exists or not.

Comment: @AkhilP, the question was not explanatory enough. However, I have edited my answer. Please have a look if it helps.

Comment: I think it will work without `$and` also. Just use the two conditions two find.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query for one option of `name`:

```
db.places.find({amenities: {$exists: true}, 'amenities.name':'wifi'})
```

Also can try this query, if multiple options to check for `name`:-

```
var findQuery = {amenities: {$exists: true}, 'amenities.name':'wifi' , 'amenities.name':'projector'}

db.places.find(findQuery);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. Please have a look at multiple options it is resulting an empty array. Even my database is having matches with the query.

Comment: Updated the query as per your requirement. I think your question is not clear enough to let someone help you in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Please try executing following query

```
db.places.find({
    amenities : {
        $exist : true
    },
    amenities : {
        $elemMatch : {
            name : {
                $in : ['wifi', 'projector']
            }
        }
    }
})
```

In above mentioned query [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator will check for existence of amenities field in document and [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator will match amenities array containing name field with following values

(1) wifi

(2) projector

Comment: have in mind that this will return only first matched element `elemMatch` specific :-)

Comment: It is returning documents which are matching at least one amenity in the `$in : ['wifi', 'projector']`. But I want documents which must have bothe  `['wifi', 'projector']`