# How I can select only one field from every object in array using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have schema:

```
{
  name: String,
  surname: String,
  note: String,
  someField: String,
  secondSomeField: String
  blackList: [{
     userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
     reason: String
  }]
}
```

I need select document with all fields, but in blackList field I need select only userId. Example what I want:

```
{
      name: "John",
      surname: "Doe",
      note: "bwrewer",
      someField: "saddsa",
      secondSomeField: "sadsd",
      blackList: [58176fb7ff8d6518baf0c931, 58176fb7ff8d6518baf0c932, 58176fb7ff8d6518baf0c933, 58176fb7ff8d6518baf0c934]
}
```

How I can do this? When I do

```
Schema.find({_id: myCustomUserId}, function(err, user) {
      //{blackList: [{userId: value}, {userId: value}]}
      //but i need
      //{blackList: [value, value, value]}
})
```

Comment: It's answer :
`Schema.aggregate(
            {$match: {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(myCustomId)} },
            {$project: {blackList: "$blackList.userId", name: true, surname: true, someField: true}}
).exec(fn)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Schema.aggregate( {$match: {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(myCustomId)} }, {$project: {blackList: "$blackList.userId", name: true, surname: true, someField: true}} ).exec(fn)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the field by default:

```
{
  name: String,
  surname: String,
  note: String,
  someField: String,
  secondSomeField: String
  blackList: [{
     userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
     reason: {type:String, select:false}
  }]
}
```

If you simply want to exclude in that query:

```
Schema
    .find({_id: myCustomUserId})
    .select("-blackList.reason")
    .exec(function (err, user) {
      //your filtered results
})
```

Not tested but they should work both.

Comment: I didnot test, but I tested a similar query, and result was:
`blackList: [{userId: id}, {userId: id}]`
but I need: `[id, id, id]`, becouse i will exec next query: `Schema.find({_id: {$nin: arrayOfIds}})`

Comment: You can keep the first query in this way and edit the next query using `$elemMatch`. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040562/how-to-search-in-array-of-object-in-mongodb

Comment: elemMatch - for search in array, it's not help for me.
I need search users, who are not in my blackList

Comment: i try query alfredopacino, It's not work(
result is: blackList: [{userId: id}, {userId: id}]

((