# mongodb find array elements inside array

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

- i am new to mongo db.
- I am trying to render my toyota car manufacturer alone.
- written mongo db query code but its not producing results.
  var cursor = db.collection('user-data').find( { carManufacturer: { $eq: toyota } } );
- can you guys tell me how to fix it providing my code below

```or-tag-here
router.get('/cars', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("kumari5");
  res.render('cars.hbs');
  var toyota = [];
  mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    var cursor = db.collection('user-data').find( { carManufacturer: { $eq: toyota } } );

    cursor.forEach(function(doc, err) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      toyota.push(doc);
    }, function() {
      db.close();
      res.render('data', {items: toyota});
      console.log(toyota);
    });
  });
});



{
  "_id": ObjectId("590a2495bd1d3a356074d36e"),

  "DateBough": "21",
  "Owner": "Female",
  "carManufacturer": ["toyota", "19"],
  "Expiry": null
}

{
  "_id": ObjectId("347834783478873478788734"),

  "DateBough": "21",
  "Owner": "Female",
  "carManufacturer": ["bmw", "19"],
  "Expiry": null
}

{
  "_id": ObjectId("34634738468299221182338989"),

  "DateBough": "21",
  "Owner": "Female",
  "carManufacturer": ["benz", "19"],
  "Expiry": null
}

{
  "_id": ObjectId("47347347834783487437834734"),

  "DateBough": "21",
  "Owner": "Female",
  "carManufacturer": ["toyota", "19"],
  "Expiry": null
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search in array of object in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040562/how-to-search-in-array-of-object-in-mongodb)

Comment: `{ carManufacturer: { $in: toyota }`

Comment: { carManufacturer:  'toyota' }