# How to find record matching the nested key laravel mongodb jenssegers

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I am using jenssegers mongodb package in laravel for querying mongodb. How to retrieve the records matching only the games as cricket in the below json document.

```
      {
       "_id": ObjectId("53402597d852426020000002"),
       "contact": "987654321",
       "dob": "01-01-1991",
       "gender": "M",
       "name": "Tom Benzamin",
       "user_name": “tombenzamin”,   
       “Personal_info”:[
            hobbies:{
                "games": "cricket",
                "favfilms": "lotr",
                "favfood": "burger"
            }
]
       }

    }
```

Comment: Could you share your relationship configuration (model class)?

Comment: No relationship is configured so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`whereRaw`](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#raw-expressions) method combined with [`elemMatch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040562/how-to-search-in-array-of-object-in-mongodb):

```
DB::collection('users')->where(
    'Personal_info.hobbies',
    'elemMatch',
    [ 'games' => 'cricket' ]
)->get()
```

Comment: Suppose if Personal_info has array of json. edited the question

Comment: @oldrock I've updated the answer, please kindly check

Answer (score 2):

```
$crickets = DB::collection('games')->where('Personal_info.hobbies.games', 'cricket')->get();
```

something like this should work

Comment: if Personal_info info is an array like this Personal_info[] then how can i access the inner level key

Comment: ...->where('Personal_info["hobbies"].games', 'cricket')->get();

Comment: Hey, the answer which is given by @Alfa was working. Thanks so much for your help.